# how will sstableloader update new data in cassandra 1.0.12?

Tags: cassandra

I want some understanding of sstableloader in cassandra 1.0.12

I have few set of rows inserted recently in cassandra 1

What will happen if I load old set of rows stored in sstables with same key using sstableloader?

Will it update same rows with old values or my recently inserted values will be preserved?

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra works on a "last write wins" scenario. If you were to rerun the SSTableLoader with the old data, it would write that old data into Cassandra, overwriting any data occupying the keys in-question.

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra 4.x is already available for production and even soon 5.x will be joining, would you think about upgrade your cluster ?
Yes, Your old data would be override with new data.